# How to keep grid cell height and width the same

Tags: wpf, grid, height, width, cell

I need to keep the `Grid` cell height = width when resizing.

### The working code using a viewBox:

```
  <Viewbox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gray" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Gray" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Black" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
```

Thank's to H.B. for the idea to use a viewBox! :)

Comment: Looks like you've missed out the code!

Comment: You should click the checkmark outline next to Matt West's answer to accept it, since it answered your original question. Also please avoid asking multiple questions in one or transforming your original question into something completely different. If you have problems with clipping search SO and if there is nothing that helps ask a new question about just this problem. (Unless of course fixing the clipping itself is considered a hack and you actually want a **better solution**, which also implies that your question in fact has not been answered sufficiently)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is probably using the shared-size features of the `Grid` control, but this sadly prevents stretching the whole grid. e.g.

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"   Content="Lorem"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Content="Lorem ipsum"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" Content="Lorem ipsum dolor"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red"   Content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit"/>
</Grid>
```

One could place this in a `Viewbox` but the resize behavior of that is probably not what you want, since it zooms the contents. Maybe you can find a way to make this usable in your context.

Answer (score 5):

WPF provides a `UniformGrid` - you might find this more helpful for what you are trying to do. Here is an article that demonstrates it:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/308222008124636PM/3.aspx

To keep things square just bind the grid's `Width` property to its own `ActualHeight` property:

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

Comment: Except that `UniformGrid` doesn't keep its children in the shape of squares when resizing.

Comment: Updated to meet this requirement

Comment: hmm, this will keep the children square (assuming you don't set `Columns` or `Rows`), but it won't scale properly if the height is bigger than the width of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) instead, or you can try something like:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="grid" >
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=RowDefinitions[0].Height}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=RowDefinitions[1].Height}" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just so you know: In general if you agree with an answer that someone else already gave you should just up their answer instead of repeating it again.