# Resizing window content gets clipped

Tags: wpf, resize, window

I need help with this code:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Gray" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Gray" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Black" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"></Label>
        </Grid>
```

The problem is, when the window's height is larger than it's width, the grid inside the window gets clipped. Can someone help me please?

Comment: As you have decided to ask a new question i assume you are satisfied with the answer on your previous one, please accept the answer given there as i noted in my earlier comment.

Comment: @H.B. Actually no, as I said, the grid gets clipped, so it's width and height isn't the same all the time. The previous post is only half answered.

Comment: -.- then don't ask a new question. And no, the width and height is always the same, you just **cannot see that** at all times.

Comment: I know the answer to this question but whats the point of answering it since I know you won't give me credit... Just kidding. But I do agree with H.B. - I will continue to try to figure out the answer to your updated question but I would like credit for answering the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid clipping content when resizing the window, use a viewBox. Thank's to H.B. for pointing this out!
Here's the link to the original post I made : [How to keep grid cell height and width the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922395/how-to-keep-grid-cell-height-and-width-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the grid in a scroll viewer?

If the case is you don't want to use a scroll viewer could you bind the Grids MaxWidth and MaxHeight to the Windows Width and Height?

Comment: I suspect that the asker does not want to have scrollbars but the same behavior as the Height resizing that can be seen in the code sample.