# Grid's Row Width equals to It's another Column's Height (In XAML)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, grid

How to set grid's row width to another column's height of same grid in XAML?
The contents of grids are in view box, and upon changing size of the window they should adjust their size as per requirement.

I have tried sizesharing option as,

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="../Resources/ABC.png"/>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
        <TextBlock Text="ABC"/>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

but the contents are continuously flickering even on not changing the size of window.

Comment: Flickering is happens because of Viewbox. As the size of one content's width changes, the other content's height is also changes which then results the width of first content to its previous value and it eventually results the again change in height of second content. This happens again and again and the flickering happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SharedSizeGroups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922395/how-to-keep-grid-cell-height-and-width-the-same/5925113#5925113)) or just [bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) via [`ElementName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname(v=vs.110).aspx) (you can name the target column/row).

Comment: I tried it but the contents are continuously flickering (even on not changing the size of window).

Comment: That happens when binding i presume? Use size sharing then.

Comment: It happens on size sharing. Now my question is edited, look at this.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir You're trying to share a size between a row and column separately of the same Grid? Never done that before, could be a culprit? If we could see the actual "flicker" behavior it would be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: @ChrisW. you can run this code at your end to check this behavior.